# MySQL and polish words

Tags: mysql, character

I have noticed a problem with "non-english" (polish) characters using MySQL.

query "select 'abcde'='ąbćdę'" returns "1" and the strings are not equals ...

could you help me ? :) thx!!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For utf8_general_ci they are equal (with the exception of ł, which is not considered a bug by MySQL), and since 5.6 you can also use utf8_unicode_520_ci which handles all Polish characters correctly. Use utf8_polish_ci to treat accented and unaccented characters as different.

```
select 'abcde'='ąbćdę' COLLATE utf8_polish_ci
>> 0
```

Demo of 'not a bug'

```
select 'abcde'='ąbćdę' COLLATE utf8_general_ci
>> 1

select 'abcdel'='ąbćdęł' COLLATE utf8_general_ci
>> 0
```

See the bug report here: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=9604

Comment: It's worth noting that in MySQL 5.6 you can use "utf8_unicode_520_ci" colllation which handles the ł case the same way as utf8_general_ci does with other polish characters.

Comment: Thanks @bigfun. Added this information to the answer

Comment: i'm having a similar issue with `ş` and `s` being treated as identical values. i've tried a number of different collations already and none of them work. any idea? [here is my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53217875/which-collation-to-use-so-that-%C5%9F-and-s-are-treated-as-unique-values)

Comment: Romanian an Turkish treat the S's differently.  Polish treats the og  Here's a table of all letters, most accented letters, and all utf8 collations:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/utf8_collations.html .  It shows which collations have different "letters" for ogoneks, etc.

Answer (score -3):

You can replace Ł to L and ł to l in MYSQL query, like this:

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE('abcdel', 'Ł', 'L'), 'ł', 'l') = REPLACE(REPLACE('ąbćdęł', 'Ł', 'L'), 'ł', 'l') COLLATE utf8_general_ci
>> 1
```

and from now all diacritic letters equals to their non-diacritic equivalents.