# MySQL, polish characters and duplicate insert statement

Tags: sql, mysql, database, character-encoding

I've got a problem with inserting two rows to table. The database is in UTF8. The problem seems to be connected to the collation. This statement works:

```
insert into test(code,text) values('xx','aaa');
```

However when i try to add other row to the table:

```
insert into test(code,text) values('xx','aąą');
```

it fails with duplicate entry error. It looks like a and ą (special polish character) are threated the same. The weird thing is that when i set all collations to utf8_unicode_ci it still does not work :/ 
Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: We had the same thing yesterday. Hang on...

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL and polish words ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506338/mysql-and-polish-words)

Comment: Changing column collation to polish_ci solved the problem. But is it possible to use unicode collation? I'm asking because this table won't be used to polish entries only.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

`insert into test(code,text) values('xx',N'aąą');`

The letter N is for Unicode insert.

Comment: im having [a similar issue.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53217875/which-collation-to-use-so-that-%C5%9F-and-s-are-treated-as-unique-values) do you know which collation i should use?