# MySQL Connector - removes polish characters

Tags: c#, mysql, utf-8, mysql-connector

When I use:

```
INSERT ... 'ąść' ...
```

it adds the value 'asc'. Why does this happen? I wrote `CHARACTER SET utf8` at end of table declaration, also used `COLLATE utf8 polish ci`. I also tried:

```
INSERT ... VALUE ( N'ąść' )
```

but it doesn't work. N - for unicode like someone wrote [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3516460/mysql-polish-characters-and-duplicate-insert-statement)

Answer (score 1):

Try to issue

```
SET NAMES utf8
```

before INSERT statement.

[SET NAMES utf8 in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159434/set-names-utf8-in-mysql)

[how to select mysql query with foreign language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9174881/how-to-select-mysql-query-with-foreign-language)