# After PHP migration encoding SQL databases

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, migration

I import data from MySQL (`utf8_general_ci`) to external MSSQL/pdo_dblib (`Polish_CI_AS`)
I saving in MSSQL by connection like this:

```
new PDO('dblib:host=hostname;dbname=databasename;charset=UTF-8, login, password);
```

Works perfectly, but yesterday was migration from PHP 5.3.29 (Hosting) to PHP 5.6.12 (VPS), and now in MSSQL tables data is not correct.

Polish letters like:
`ł` is now `Ĺ‚`
`ą` is now `Ä…`

It's fault migration?

Comment: Plz refer the solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506338/mysql-and-polish-words