# Which collation to use so that `ş` and `s` are treated as unique values?

Tags: mysql, collation, mysql-5.7

The issue is that `ş` and `s` are interpreted by MySQL as identical values.

I'm new to MySQL, so I have no idea which collations would view them as unique.

The collations that I've tried using which don't work are:

1. `utf8_general_ci`
2. `utf8_unicode_520_ci`
3. `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`
4. `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci`

Does anybody know which collation to use?

P.S. I also really need the collation to interpret emojis and other non-Latin characters, and, to my knowledge of MySQL and collations, the only collation able to do this is `unicode`?

Comment: those two characters are considered equivalent, at least by Unicode's collation standard. http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr15/

Comment: @Anthony i know that because that's the very issue i'm facing right now lol. thanks nonetheless.

Comment: I'm saying there wouldn't be a unicode conforming collation that would treat those characters as unique.

Comment: @Anthony ahh i see what youre saying now. my buddy just actually said `unicode_bin` will work since it doesn't strip accents

Comment: That makes sense, since unicode_bin only treats characters as code points.  But note that that isn't what collation actually is. That the mostly common mistake of how collation works. http://unicode.org/faq/collation.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`utf8_turkish_ci` and `utf8_romanian_ci` -- as shown in http://mysql.rjweb.org/utf8_collations.html

(Plus, of course, `utf8_bin`.)

For your added question:  You are looking for a "character set" (not a "collation") that can represent Emoji and other non-Latin characters -- `UTF-8` is the one to use.  In MySQL, it is `utf8mb4`.  The "collations" that are associated with that are named `utf8mb4_...`.  Collations control ordering and equality, as indicated in the first part of your question about `s` and `ş`.

MySQL's `CHARACTER SET utf8` is a subset of `utf8mb4`.  Either can handle all the "letters" in the world.  But only utf8mb4 can handle Emoji and some Chinese characters.